# How do I add this jQuery into my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm extremely new to both JS and jQuery, and I've got this code:

```
<html>
<style>
/**
* Default attributes for gadget body.
*/
body {
 font-family: Arial;
background: none transparent;
padding: 0px;
}
html, body, #map_canvas {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"></div> 
<script>
var APIKey = "MyKeyValueIsInHere";   
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var locationTest = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=55.653363&lon=12.547604&zoom=18&addressdetails=1';
var lat = 55.653363;
var lng = 12.547604;

function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
// set the options for zoom level and map type
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
// create a map in the map_canvas div element
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
map.setCenter(latlng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: latlng

        });
        alert(locationTest);
        var text = JSON.parse(locationTest);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var houseNumber = text.address.house_number;
        var road = text.address.road;
        var suburb = text.address.suburb;
        var zipCode = text.address.postcode;
        var city = text.address.city;

        var address = road + " " + houseNumber + ", " + zipCode + " " + suburb + " i " + city;


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(address);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
}
function loadScript() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + APIKey + "&sensor=false&callback=initialize";  

document.body.appendChild(script);
}   

loadScript();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And i need to incorporate the following code :

```
$('#c').load('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=55.653363&lon=12.547604&zoom=18&addressdetails=1', function (response) {
console.log('response is', response);
var b = $('#c').html();
console.log('b is', b);
var a = JSON.parse(b);
console.log('a is ', a);
$('#d').html(a.address.neighbourhood);
});
```

Basically, this code is supposed to show a location on google maps, the location is set by long and latitude. On the marker, I want an info box to pop up with the address. The jQuery code i've found, seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p0zLsgs0/2/), but I have fallen short now that I have to include it into my JS. I hope someone can help me, I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Just add it right before your closing body tag and it should work fine

Comment: jQuery is nothing but a JavaScript library so it can run together.

Comment: But let's say i want the current infowindow, which is on the marker, to have the information that comes out of the jQuery. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add jquery script link to your  tag.

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, i completely forgot about this :)